# Maximum value problem

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, absolute-value

A function $\hspace{0.1cm}$$f:[0,1]\to[-1,1]$$\hspace{0.1cm}$ satisfying$\hspace{0.1cm}$ $|f(x)|\leq x$$\hspace{0.1cm}$ $\forall x\in[0,1]$.

Then find the maximum value of:

$|\int_{0}^{1}(f^2(x)-f(x))dx|$

My attempt:

$|\int_{0}^{1}(f^2(x)-f(x))dx|\leq \int_{0}^{1}|f^2(x)-f(x)|dx\leq \int_{0}^{1}(|f^2(x)|-|f(x)|)dx\leq \int_{0}^{1}(x^2-x)dx=-\frac{1}{6}$

But it is not possible because absolute value is always greater than equal to zero.Please someone help me to find its maximum value.Thanks

Comment: You made a mistake:
$|f^2(x)-f(x)|\le |f^2(x)|+|f(x)|$
In fact you did:
$|f^2(x)-f(x)|\le |f^2(x)|-|f(x)|$

Comment: No, I write it as $|f^2(x)-f(x)|\leq |f^2(x)|-|f(x)|$

Comment: Scientifica has pointed out that you've violated a property of absolute values, not that you didnt intend to write it that way.

Comment: But that's incorrect, $\lvert f^2(x)\rvert - \lvert f(x)\rvert \leqslant \lvert f^2(x)-f(x)\rvert$.

Comment: It's false. For any $a$ and $b$ real numbers we have:
$||a|-|b||\le |a-b|\le |a|+|b|$

Comment: Oh yes i write  $|f(x)|\leq x$ implies $$-|f(x)|\leq -x$$  which is wrong it should be $$-|f(x)|\geq -x$$

Comment: Don't forget that multiplying by -1 reverses the direction of the inequality..

Comment: But now how i can write in form of $\leq$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

\begin{align}
\left|\int_{0}^{1} f(x)^{2} - f(x) \,\mathrm{d}x  \right|
\le \int_{0}^{1} |f(x)|^{2} + |f(x)| \, \mathrm{d}x \le \int_{0}^{1} x^{2} + x \, \mathrm{d}x = \frac{5}{6}.
\end{align}
So the maximum is at most $5/6$. However, let $f(x) = -x$. Then 
\begin{align}
\left|\int_{0}^{1} f(x)^{2} - f(x) \,\mathrm{d}x  \right| = \int_{0}^{1} x^{2} + x \, \mathrm{d}x = \frac{5}{6}. 
\end{align}
So the maximum is indeed $5/6$.